# Loss of image quality in IE?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, explorer

Within my template, my img css contains the following lines of code:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Whenever I place an image inside of one of my div or set widths tags, the image appropriately shrinks and modifies itself as within the CSS.

However in IE (not Chrome or Firefox), the image becomes pixelated upon the auto adjustment.

I've looked around for solutions, but nothing has worked in my favor yet.

Answer (score 0):

IE's image rendering isn't the greatest. Try adding this:

```
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/ie-fix-bicubic-scaling-for-images/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that, including adding it after the css in it's own img tag. Still I'm getting pixelation.

Comment: Can you also add `width:auto` to your `img` CSS and see if that does anything?

Comment: I added the width: auto to the css tag and it didn't do anything... If it's anything, the main fix is with PNGs upon the adjustment. That's were I'm seeing the problem the most. The edges are pixelated, unlike the smooth texture you get in Firefox and Chrome.